# Secondary math font definition

Tags: fonts, xetex

We are using XeTeX, and struggling to map mathematics fonts for secondary fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}
\setmathrm{Palatino Linotype}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[version={sfsansbold}]{MinionPro-Regular}
\def\doall{\displaystyle Text for Sample \alpha+\beta=\gamma-\left\{\frac12\right\}+\frac12}

\begin{document}
{Text for Sample $\doall$\par}
{Text for Sample \mathversion{bold}{$\doall$}\par}
{\sffamily Text for Sample $\doall$\par}
{\sffamily Text for Sample \mathversion{sfsansbold}{$\doall$}\par}
\end{document}
```

We are getting the output for the same as below:

[image]

We need the output as below:

[image]

Appreciated for your help.

Comment: You get maths typeset with Computer Modern fonts. You have to declare  to `mathspec` which fonts you want to use for maths. See §4 of the documentation for details, p.3 sqq.

Comment: I'm not sure you can load `mathspec` and `unicode-math` at same time they are different attempts to set up math fonts. For unicode-math at least you need math specific  fonts with an opentype MATH table, which I don't think is the case for the fonts you have here